# how to give permission to read and write data from PDkeychain when device is locked

Tags: ios, keychain

Can someone please help me how to give permissions to read or write data from Keychain when device is locked with passcode? Also If the key changes, will the existing market users faces problems when they update the latest build?

I found we can give permission to read or write data from key chain when device is locked by passing the key-value "(_*bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,(*_bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,". But by changing this dictionay will the existing users have any problem in reading or writing data?

**Existing code in market build -**

```
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData,kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass,
                       key, kSecAttrAccount,
                       [self serviceName], kSecAttrService,
                       nil];
```

**Updated Code -**

```
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnData,kSecClassGenericPassword, kSecClass,
                       key, kSecAttrAccount,
                       [self serviceName], kSecAttrService,(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,
                       nil];**
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found we can give permission to read or write data from key chain when device is locked by passing the key-value "(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways,(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,".

Answer (score -1):

http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad/

"Never use kSecAttrAccessibleAlways. If you are storing user data in the keychain it's safe to assume that it should be protected.

In general, you should always use at least kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked to ensure that data is not accessible when the device is locked. If you have to access data while the device is locked use kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock."